# Distribute 4 SKSpriteNodes along SkScene Width programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I know scene coordinates are (0,0) at center so how can i distribute 4 SKNodes along the width using a for loop

```
for index 1...4 {

 let node = SKNode() 
 node.postion = evenly distribute along the scene width. who can i do it?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the width of the scene divided by the number of nodes minus 1. This would then be multiplied by the index minus 1, then added to the minimum x value of your scene.

```
let widthRange = scene.frame.maxX - scene.frame.minX

for index 1...4 { 
    let node = SKNode() 
    node.postion = scene.frame.minX + widthRange/(4-1) * (index-1)
}
```

This should place each node an equal distance away from each other along the width of the scene, starting from each edge.

If your index for the for loop doesn't start at 1, the code would need to be modified to something like this:

```
let widthRange = scene.frame.maxX - scene.frame.minX

var counter = 0
for index 352...356 { 
    let node = SKNode() 
    node.postion = scene.frame.minX + widthRange/(4-1) * counter
    counter+=1
}
```

If you're unsure of which version to use, use the second version, as it's less reliant on the format of the for loop (as long as you reset `counter` to 0 before every time you use this).

If you need any clarifications as to what does what, feel free to ask.

### Edit

This should clarify what the code actually does.

**`let widthRange = scene.frame.maxX - scene.frame.minX`** is used to get the size of the scene, then set it to a variable that is used later. Making this a variable is sort of optional as you could just use the scene size,  however I put it this way so it's less messy.

**`var counter = 0`** simply makes a counter variable, that's used in the for-loop, to place the nodes. Make sure to set it to 0 before every time you run the loop. **`counter+=1`** is then used later so each node is multiplied by an increasing value, which creates the different x-positions. (I'll get into that later)

**`node.postion = scene.frame.minX + widthRange/(4-1) * counter`** is the complicated line. First, I use `scene.frame.minX` to start placement from the lowest width/x-position. `widthRange/(4-1)` is a little harder to understand. It uses the scenes width (from earlier), then divides by one less than the amount of nodes. The best way to understand this, is that to cut a rectangle (only in a single direction) so it has 2 cuts through it (2 of the nodes), and 2 edges (the other 2 nodes), you would need 3 sections. (The rectangle would be cut into 3). This gets the distance between each node. The pattern of `#ofNodes-1` follows for every amount of nodes. The `* counter` part is the part that makes the node's x-position actually change. Since every time the loop is gone through, counter increases by 1 (starting at 0) the amount of "sections" from before (`widthRange/(4-1)`) is increased by 1.

Comment: @user431791 Added to my answer. Take a look now